# What is the name and properties of a category C with hom(C) is subclass of ob(C)?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Suppose we have a category $C$ such as $hom(C) \subset ob(C)$ (so every arrow $f: a \rightarrow b$ of $C$ is also an object of $C$). What is the name and the main properties of such category?

Comment: In my opinion, that's just not the sort of thing that should be going on in a category. There's nothing *technically* wrong about it, but for conceptual simplicity objects and morphisms should always be distinct, for the same reason it is usually required that $\mathrm{Hom}(a,b)\cap\mathrm{Hom}(c,d)=\varnothing$ unless $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: The more meaningful property is $\text{hom}_C(a,b)\in\text{Ob}(C)$ for every $a,b\in \text{Ob}(C)$(_self-enriched categories_, under certain assumptions).

Comment: With the right version of set theory, it shouldn't even be possible to state this condition. (ZFC has the stupid property that the question "$a \subset b$?" makes sense for every pair of sets $a$ and $b$. Are you ever going to ask whether $\mathbb{R} \subset 3$? No.)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a name for the property that you mention, for the simple reason that this property is not very meaningful.

Look at it this way:

Suppose you have a category $C$ which has the property that you mention, and then another category $D$ which has exactly the same objects, but the morphisms are written with red ink (just to enphasize some *super-silly* difference in naming) or have an overbar, if you prefer.

Now, we certainly agree that $C$ and $D$ should have the same mathematical properties, since they are effectively the *same* category, yet $C$ has your property, while $D$ does not, since its morphisms are written in red (or have an overbar) and the elements of $Ob(D)$ are all still in black (and have no overbar). So your property is very *fragile* and not respected even by isomorphic categories.

A mathematical property - to be considered meaningful - needs to respect equivalence of categories and even more isomorphism of categories. Yours does not.
This is called the [principle of equivalence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) in nlab

In his comment above @Oskar mentions the more interesting self-enriched categories, which is perhaps what you were looking for.

By the way, the collection of morphisms of $C$ is called $Mor(C)$

Comment: In my reading, an injection $J:Mor(C)\to Ob(C)$ would suffice in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This idea just came to my mind recently!

I haven't found anything about it, but wrote a short [note](http://renyi.hu/~aladar/potential-definition-weak.pdf), where I called such a thing a '*folded category*', and I wanted to model infinite dimensional categories by them, starting out from an unbiased version of bicategories.

Then I posted it on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153204/a-potential-definition-of-weak-omega-categories/157774), but nobody answered.

Finally, I found out that some elementary feature seems missing: namely I had to add one more composition for second dimension, but I kept on hoping that it will already generate all we need. Now, I think, there is no way to escape from introducing one more operation for each dimension, and with that, it seems that things get the same (or even more) complicated as with any original naive approach... :(

Comment: Many thanks you for the link to your note. I think I should try to get all things in one piece before marking answers as accepted (as I'm not very good at such math).

Comment: I'm still not sure that this is what you were looking for. And, it didn't lead me nowhere..